# How to properly define Array param for function?

Tags: javascript

I am working on project, where I want to make intellisense give me more options. I am defining what I need to pass into functions with the required attribute @param.

Unfortunately I can't access the page [usejsdoc.org](http://usejsdoc.org/) anymore, where I learned how to use it.

So the main problem is that I want to pass multiple arrays into one function so I use (...data). When defining it in @param it doesn't work anymore, so it seems to be only working for one array.

This is my function

```js
/**
   * Initializes the Animation
   * @param {...Object[]} data[]
   * @param {number} data[].amount
   * @returns {MyAnimationClass}
   */
  init(...data) {
    try {
      data.items.forEach(arr => {
        arr.forEach((item, i) => {
          this._addTimeline(item, i);
        });
      });
    } catch (ex) {
      this._logger.logException(ex);
    }
    return this;
  }
```

And how I want to use it:

```js
myAnimation.init(
  [
    { amount: 10 }
  ],
  [
    { amount: 15 }
  ]
);
```

Does anybody know, how I define it properly, so it gives me the right intellisense?

Comment: you can use https://jsdoc.app/ if that link is down. Awyway, it sounds like you want: `@param {Array<{amount: Number}>} data`

Comment: Hey @briosheje. Thanks for the info about jsdoc.app.
I modified your example with my excpectation and its working fine now:result:

`@param {Array<Array<{amount: Number}>>} data`

Edit: `@param {...Array<{amount: Number}>} data` is also working fine

Comment: That signature doesn't match the input provided. That signature, in a "readable" javascript sample, is: `[[{amount: 10][{amount: 15}]]` (note the **double** square brackets). Are you sure that's what you want?..